# Cannot get MySQL data which is too large

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I am setting up a website which stores a large (serialized) array of arrays specific to each user. The large array is serialized and then the database is updated to its new value. Also, the new array is added to the $_SESSION[] array which is used for the period the user is logged in. I can UPDATE the array fine with up to 4 of these arrays in the large array but after that the data does not seem to UPDATE properly.

The MySQL UPDATE query returns 1 even after the 3rd array has been added and the $_SESSION[] array seems to contain all the right data but when the user logs out and then back in again, the array does not seem to be copied to the $_SESSION[] array as it should whenever the user logs in. If only 4 of these arrays are stored in the large array, the data can be fetched from the database no problem. I increased the length of the database field beyond what would be required (and then increased it faaaar beyond what should be required) but it did not help.

When I go to phpMyAdmin, I can see that the array is updated successfully until after array 3 when the serialised array stops abruptly (in the middle of a sentence in the serialised array) but I think this might be an issue with phpMyAdmin because alongside the array edit box it says 'Because of its length, this field might not be editable' so maybe phpMyAdmin is just not bothering to load the rest of the array into the tiny textarea.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? Is there anything I may not be aware of (I am a beginner with MySQL but it seems to have been working okay up until now).

The code used to update the database is like this:

```
$_SESSION['data']['user']['templates'][$_SESSION['edit']['templateNo']] = $template;
$serializedTemplates = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($_SESSION['data']['user']['templates']));
$serializedReports = mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($_SESSION['data']['user']['reports']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email']);
$returned = mysql_query("UPDATE rmusers SET templates='$serializedTemplates', reports='$serializedReports' WHERE email='$email'") or die (mysql_error());
```

The 'reports' and 'email' array elements are not really relevant.

The code used to retrieve the array from the database is like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rmusers WHERE email='" . $_POST['email'] ."'");
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (strlen(unserialize($userRow['templates'])) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['data']['user']['templates'] = unserialize($userRow['templates']);
}
```

Also, sorry I have used the word 'array' about 25 times in the above question :)

Comment: What type of field is templates in the database? You should also be able to check the data in phpMyAdmin by viewing it (instead of editing), and clicking the icon to expand truncated text fields (it looks like this: -> T <- )

Comment: Just how big is this data chunk compared to mysql's "max_allowed_packet" setting?

Comment: field type is text. I was not aware of the "max_allowed_packet" setting - that may be the problem. How can I change it?

Comment: The text type has a [maximum length of 65535](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) characters, maybe you hit that?

Comment: yes, that is exactly the number of characters I have. any way around this limit?

Comment: You can use longtext instead, which has a much higher limit

Comment: what are the disadvantages of using longtext?

Comment: It needs one more byte to store the text length, but that's the only one I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field type is `text`, which has a maximum length of 65535 characters. Switch over to `longtext`, that has a theoretical limit of 4GB. However keep in mind that the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html) says:

> The effective maximum length of LONGTEXT columns also depends on the configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and available memory.

Also see the documentation of the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting:

> The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB.

Comment: "There's no practical difference between the four text types" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314682/what-is-the-disadvantage-to-using-a-mysql-longtext-sized-field-when-every-entry

Comment: You might want to consider `LARGEBLOB` (or `MEDIUMBLOB`, ~ 16 MB limit) instead. Blob types are binary which is what a serialized string in PHP is which can prevent further problems.