# Minimum Size of TEXT and LONGTEXT

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

A column of my database stores a long text. Most of the texts are smaller than the limit of TEXT (64KB). However about 0.1% of them are long texts (> 64KB). Originally I use TEXT as the column datatype, and I have to ignore the entries with long text. But if I use LONGTEXT as the datatype, I found the database size doubles. The total size of entries with long text should be much smaller than the total size of entries with normal text.

Is there some kind of “minimum size” for TEXT and LONGTEXT that makes each entry with LONGTEXT datatype larger than entry with TEXT datatype and causes the difference in storage?

More specifically, one entry with TEXT datatype takes about 1KB. One entry with LOnGTEXT takes about 2KB.

I am using innoDB, and the other columns' types are:

varchar(50)
int(10)
varchar(70)
varchar(12)
varchar(7)
varchar(50)
varchar(50)
datetime

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the disadvantage to using a MySQL longtext sized field when every entry will fit within a mediumtext sized field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314682/what-is-the-disadvantage-to-using-a-mysql-longtext-sized-field-when-every-entry)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL stores BLOB data (including `TEXT` and `LONGTEXT`) inline and prefixes it with a byte count. `TEXT` stores that count in a two-byte prefix, so it can store up to 2^16 - 2 bytes of information. `LONGTEXT` stores the count in a four-byte prefix, so it can store up to 2^32 - 4 bytes of information.

Storing the fields as `LONGTEXT` wouldn't automatically cause the database size to double since the only thing that is double is the size of the prefix. However, *changing* it from `TEXT` to `LONGTEXT` could theoretically double the size because MySQL is copying the information when it changes it and doesn't automatically release it when it's done.

Comment: There can be a smarter way for MySQL to store the size, no? Like storing two bits as the size of the prefix, which can be 1-4. It would only add to the size in cases where most records have a huge size, which case it's negligible.

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak I think you're confusing something here. The prefix is itself a byte count and the size is inconsequential. The issue remains that MySQL could be allocating room for more data and not releasing it when that room isn't consumed. That's much more significant than the two additional bytes used to store the count.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing a growth in size because of a prefix each `LONGTEXT` value stores.

From the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

> Each LONGTEXT value is stored using a 4-byte length prefix that
>   indicates the number of bytes in the value.