# MySQL: Is there a lack of performance by using LONGTEXT instead of MEDIUMTEXT?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqldatatypes

I know the principle of using the smallest data type possible, but I wonder if this would apply to TEXT / MEDIUMTEXT / LONGTEXT in MySQL? Is there a performance issue if I use LONGTEXT instead of MEDIUMTEXT?
I've found the question [What is the disadvantage to using a MySQL longtext sized field when every entry will fit within a mediumtext sized field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314682/what-is-the-disadvantage-to-using-a-mysql-longtext-sized-field-when-every-entry)
 but I think this isn't the answer to the performance question?

Is it just a matter of a bit more storage for LONGTEXT?

When should I prefer MEDIUMTEXT to LONGTEXT?

Comment: You should use the data type you really need ..  the difference is only related  to the max number of char .allowed  for each data type  ..the *TEXT   datatype have dinamic length  .. and use only the space required  by the content  (plus some few bytes for le set the single real length)

Comment: Complementing what @scaisEdge wrote, If the inserted data of the field is too long it would compromise performance in two ways, querying it conditionally and querying it to get the value, like a field with a base64 image, but only because of the size of the text inserted there not by the type. So if you have a TEXT with maximum size and a LONGTEXT with one char, the LONGTEXT will be queried faster.

Comment: So for example, I have values about 100000 chars, for the read/write performance it doesn't matter if I use TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT? In this case I would always use LONGTEXT to have the larger limit for the future. I still don't see any advantage of the smaller text types?

Comment: If you know that your data will fit in the smaller type, you save a byte or two per record because the length field is smaller. If you have many millions of records, those bytes add up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is the length field in the row data. Using `MEDIUMTEXT` instead of `LONGTEXT` saves 1 byte per record. If you have 100 million records, that saves 100 MB. There was a time when that was a significant amount of disk space.

The difference could also be significant if you're running up against the size limit for database rows. The text of `*TEXT` data is stored in files external to the table data, so it doesn't count against the limit, but I believe the size field is in the table so it does count.

But if neither of these is an issue, go ahead and use the largest type, to future-proof your schema.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that once you get beyond what can be stored on-record, the 1/2/3/4-byte "length" thingie vanishes.  That is, the 3 never manifests itself in InnoDB storage.  There is a 20-byte pointer to the off-row overflow, regardless of the size of the overflow.

Comment: @RickJames Good points. It might be more significant if you use `MEDIUMTEXT` when you only need `TEXT`, Then you're not filling up the disk, but you're still wasting space on length bytes.

Comment: The blind use of BIGINT wastes space faster.